# Widescreen check on normal screen

Tags: browser, cross-browser, screen, compatibility, widescreen

I work normal screen and I develop some web application. When the application goes on widescreen some of the pages looks weired. Is there any way I can view my web page as it looks in Widescreen on my normal screen.

Someway to either change resolution for only IE or is there any way (add-on in IE) that i can change resolution for on some instance.

Regards,
Piyush

Comment: Not a solution but a suggestion for good practice, when designing your web page don't rely on a particular screen width. You can design for a minimum screen width but don't rely on any particular width. If that's not the problem then perhaps you can describe what you mean by "looks weird" in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE8 press F12, then go tool > resize. Pick a size or enter a custom size.
This is the IE developer toolbar. I don't know if it's available standard in IE 7 but it is in IE8. it's also available as a seperate download.

Answer (score 2):

This online tool allows you to view websites in different screen resolutions:
http://viewlike.us/

These firefox addons allow you to change resolutions on the fly, which is really helpful if a specific project your developing with a different resolution in mind:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-firefox-plugins-test-website-resolutions/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To compensate for a widescreen, you may want to create a standard screen mode and a widescreen mode javascript. You would be able to tell if the page is wide screen or not by the ratio of the client HTML area wdith/height.

Another way to compensate for this: don't use percentage based widths and heights.

Answer (score 0):

You can always install another copy of Windows under VirtualBox and configure widescreen resolution